# Difference between “atterrir”, “échouer”, “aboutir", “déboucher"

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, choix-de-mot

> **Dans** quel bled paumé j’ai **atterri**, moi ?
>
> **Dans** quel bled paumé j’ai **échoué**, moi ?
>
> **À** quel bled paumé j’ai **abouti**, moi ?
>
> **Sur** quel bled paumé j’ai **débouché**, moi ?

When you unexpectedly arrive somewhere, end up at some place, how do those synonyms actually differ in nuances and usages?

I think "dans" cannot be used with “aboutir", “déboucher", and different prepositions are required.

Comment: Il ne faut pas oublier le verbe **tomber**. Dans quel bled paumé est-que je suis tombé? Si on utilize **bled**, le mot tomber est du même registre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Dans quel bled paumé j’ai atterri, moi ?" est assez familier, sans être grossier.

"Dans quel bled paumé j’ai échoué, moi ?" est une lamentation du même genre.

"À quel bled paumé j’ai abouti, moi ?" me semble plutôt impropre ; vous induisez par une telle expression que vous aviez une intention initiale d'arriver quelque part et le terme "aboutir" pour "arriver quelque part" est pour le moins inélégant.

"Sur quel bled paumé j’ai débouché, moi ?" me semble deux fois incorrect, d'abord à cause du "sur" initial (vous habitez "sur" Paris, aaargh), et aussi "débouché" ressort davantage de la plomberie que du déplacement des personnes.

Par ailleurs dans les quatre phrases que vous donnez en exemple, vous vous adressez à vous-même une plainte qui peut in fine être assez déplaisante pour votre interlocuteur, si vous en avez un.

Permettez-moi une suggestion simple: "Comment ai-je pu échouer en ce lieu nul ?", est peut-être un peu ampoulé, mais semble transcrire fidèlement votre sentiment. Une remarque plus générale sur l'emploi du mot arabe "bled", qui me semble un peu "risqué"(en anglais dans le texte) tant il peut évoquer pour votre interlocuteur des événements assez différents. Une recherche internet vous donnera rapidement les contextes historiques de l'émergence de ce mot dans la langue française

Answer (score 2):

For what my personal feeling is worth :

*Atterrir dans un bled*, yes, I would use it, it's fairly common and colloquial.
*Echouer dans un bled*, I would use less, perhaps more in writing.
*Aboutir à un bled, déboucher sur un bled*, I think are used more with inanimate subjects such as *la route aboutit à un bled paumé* or *la vallée débouche sur un bled paumé*.

Another common way of expressing the idea is *Dans quel bled paumé je me suis retrouvé!*

Answer (score 2):

*Échouer*: The translation is *stranded* and used here it carries the same meaning. Like when the river dragged you several kilometers left you somewhere, *avoir échoué* somewhere mean that you were more or less dragged here, by people, life, ... a series of events brings you there.
An example could be, when your friend told you about this awesome trip in the countryside, and when you arrive there is only 2 almost ruined house and no phone network. Here, you can say *dans quel bled paumé j'ai échoué, moi ?*
*Échoué* can also mean that you arrived in a "bad" place/situation.

*Attérir* carries the same meaning as *échoué*, but it's more about *your* choice and less about the events that brought you there.
If we re-use the precedent example, it would be the trip that you decided to do, and when you arrived in this lost place without internet, you're like *dans quel bled paumé j'ai attéri*.

However the difference between the two is small, and you can interchange them without problem, people will still understand.

The two others have a slightly different meaning. While you can use them in the same as the other, they also have a meaning related to *direction* / *path*. (I'm not sure how to make it clear in english).

*Aboutir* carries the meaning that it's the end of your travel, or the end of something (like a road, a forest,...).
For example, after walking several hours in the wood, and making your way between the brambles and others plants, you suddenly arrive in a village. Here, *abouti* can be used.
(*note*: *échoué* can als be used here, the forest can be see as something that drag you there).

*Déboucher* is almost the same as *abouti* but is really about going out of something to arrive in a place (like exiting the forest: *J'ai débouché dans ce village en sortant de la forêt*).

*Dans* can be use *aboutir*, *déboucher*, there is no restriction:
*J'ai abouti dans cette situation en suivant ce gredin*
*J'ai débouché dans cette allée en essayant d'échapper à la police*

However *déboucher* is often used you arrive in front/newt to something and not inside (e.g: *déboucher devant la statue de la liberté*).
(*note*: the other word can also be used in this situation, but *déboucher* is often better)

However, I want to say that the meaning of these words are really (**really**) close in this situation, and while I tried to distinguish them and their use, you can interchanging them in most of my example and the word still perfectly mean the same.

Here is some sentence and the word you can use (without the sentence feeling strange):

- J'ai suivi cet homme dans la rue et à travers le parc et j'ai *attéri*/*abouti* dans une boite de nuit*
- J'ai voulu suivre la piste de ce renard, et après avoir traversé la rivière j'ai *débouché*/*abouti* dans une clairière.
- Je n'aurais jamais du accepter ce travail. Dans quel coin perdu j'ai *échoué*/*attéri*.
- Tu as voulu suivre les conseils de cette fille, et regarde un peu où on a *attéri*.
- Après la mort de ma femme, j'ai quitté mon travail. Je me suis reconverti dans l'informatique, mais mon propriétaire m'a expulsé et j'ai *échoué*/*attéri* ici.
- Si nous avions tourné à droite nous aurious *débouché* sur le purgatoire et si nous avions pris à gauche, nous aurions *abouti*/*attéri*/*échoué* en enfer. Mais en continuant tout droit à travers l'antichambre des morts, nous avons finalement *abouti* au Paradis.

**TL;DR**: you can generally interchange the 4 words together, however:

- *échouer* is better when you arrive somewhere and it's not good (*échouer* en enfer)
- *atterrir* works almost everytime, it should be your default choice.
- *déboucher* and *aboutir* are better when you arrive somewhere after going through something, a long road, anything.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, all four phrases have equivalent meanings but with slight nuances. Note that “bled” is colloquial, mostly used by Algerian French to mean “village”, now widely used to mean “someplace”. In that setting, the use of the “dans” preposition can be used in all cases.

The nuance comes from the way you imply you arrive at this place. “Atterir” is by plane (from the air to the ground) that is coming at once, “échouer” is by boat (from the sea to the ground) implying it is unexpected.
“Aboutir” evokes a long process, a bit similarly to “Débouché” while the latter is more accurately used for specific geographic profiles (like exiting a gorge).

The differences are thus meant by the way you imply you arrived unexpectedly to this place.

Comment: Je m'excuse mais le mot bled est couramment utilisé en France pour parler d'un village. Et cela  ne veut pas dire "someplace"; au contraire, cela veut dire town ou village. L'anglais n'a pas d'équivalent au même registre.

Comment: C'est correct, le mot signifie "village" en arabe et est couramment utilisé en français avec ce sens. Souvent il désigne un village de manière générale ("un bled") plutot que spécifique ("ce bled"). Très bien pour l'édition, merci.

Answer (score 0):

**I** The first usage belong to colloquial language, even vulgar : it's argot.

> (TLFi)  C. P. ext., fam.
>   1. [En parlant d'un objet quelconque qui vole puis touche terre] :
>
> - Nous étions dans une loge, sur le côté du théâtre. Des hauteurs, tombait un brouhaha de conversations passionnées. Parfois, un léger papier plié en forme de flèche prenait son vol, traversait lentement l'espace et venait, aux applaudissements des galeries, atterrir sur la scène encombrée d'une légion de pupitres et d'instruments.
>     G. DUHAMEL, Chronique des Pasquier, Le Jardin des bêtes sauvages, 1934, p. 222.
>
> Arg. Arriver brusquement
>   2. [En parlant de pers.] Se trouver en un lieu, généralement sans savoir par quelle voie on y est parvenu
>
> - J'attendis fiévreusement la rentrée et dans le train mon cœur bondissait. Quand je me retrouvai dans l'appartement à la moquette pâlie, je me réveillai, brutalement; je n'avais pas atterri chez Jacques, mais à la maison; j'allais passer l'année entre ces murs.
>
> Arg. Choir (sold., 1918) : P. a crevé en atterrissant dans un trou (cycl., 1927). Arriver brusquement, s'abattre
>
> - Ma pogne a atterri en plein tarin!

**II** "échouer" is used in a sense implying that one is subjected to the action; the meaning of concept from which the figurative meaning is got is "to run aground".

> (TLFi) C. Emploi pronom. à sens passif ou subjectif

As the sens is the figurative counterpart of "run aground" ("échouer" *or* "s'échouer") and that a person is the subject the usage should not be pronominal and is therefore correct; if it were pronominal something different would be meant.

> (TLFi) 3. P. ext. [Le suj. désigne des pers.] Arriver dans un lieu inattendu **et s'y installer**.
>
> - D'un pas de flânerie, ils descendirent, hésitèrent, s'échouèrent enfin dans un petit café. (ZOLA, Œuvre, 1886, p. 145)
>
> P. anal. [En parlant d'animés non humains] ,,Auxiliaire : Le navire a échoué ou est échoué sur un banc de sable en vue des côtes. Avoir marque l'action; être, l'état qui résulte de l'action accomplie. On peut dire aussi s'échouer : Le navire s'est échoué. Au sens figuré, on ne dit pas d'une personne ou d'une entreprise qu'elle est échouée. On dit toujours :  `a` (HANSE 1949).

In conclusion, it can be said that the meaning is the same as in "**I**" but that the register is that of normal language, which, however, is not incompatible with the argotic register of "bled paumé".

**III** "Aboutir" is no  synonym of "échouer" (but same register).

> (TLFi)   Au fig. [Le suj. est exceptionnellement un animé] Arriver à un résultat, achever, réussir

Whereas in "aterrir" and "échouer" there is no conscious striving towards a goal, "aboutir" implies just the contrary.

- Après plus de quatres heures à se frayer un passage dans la jungle à coups de machette nous avons aboutit à/débouché sur une petite clairière.
  *The first choice makes for some highlighting on the striving before the event while the second makes for some highlighting of the change of environnement.*

**VI** "Déboucher" implies a new nuance yet; the sudden apparition in a given place is accompanied by an element of novelty, a more spacious place (which can be quite plain though, as in "porte qui débouche sur un couloir").

> (TLFi) A. 1.Sortir d'un endroit resserré pour passer dans un lieu plus ouvert. Déboucher dans, sur, à

That makes this fourth sentence not too likely, unless someone went through a bit of jungle before reaching the place deemed to be a "bled". The sentence "Après trois heures de cette piste du désert on débouchait sur une splendide oasis." would convey a strange idea, but it is possible to choose such a formulation, I guess.

Comment: Can you leave out the pasted part of a dictionary to make everything more concise? Because the content of dictionaries, I can check that out on my own. I'd prefer answers that are based more on native speakers' own opinion, based on how they use the language on their daily life.

Comment: How can you say that "*j'ai atteri*" is vulgar?? Do you know what vulgar means?

Comment: @Dasshoes To ignore dictionaries is to ignore the essence of the language that has been distilled for us by the hard and patient work of lexicographers, whatever their faults and misgivings; dictionaries aren't there to give us a translatin of of yesterday's language but to preserve yesterday's and today's language; finally I have to say that they are references  and that there is no reasons to discriminate against them in particular; moreover, the reproaches made to posters by the staff  and other mentors are always that the posters do not make use enough  references  (field 1)

Comment: @Dasshoes and that they should keep their opinions for themselves. I think that I provide nevertheless certain personal opinions but with the support of dictionary references when possible. I can't remove those patches as I think them essential for the obtention of what is capital in the immediate capture or re-capture of what a particular word or term is about ; I provide them specially in order to avoid to the reader to break off in getting to a dictionary so as to make precise a meaning;  they're instant reminders that are useful  to myself; how can they not be to others ? (end)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat "Argot" is vulgar in French and the two elements concerned are labelled as "argot"; I did say "even vulgar" as concerns specially two of the senses and the sense to be considered in "bled paumé j'ai atterri" is pure "argot"; that's what the dictionary says and that's what I feel about it. In fact those sentences are either nothing but "argot"  or 75 % "argot".

Comment: @LPH Si tu entends "vulgaire" dans le sens de "*Qui concerne le peuple, le quidam, le personnage quelconque.*", ok (mais sache que *vulagr* a pas forcément le même sens en anglais, et ce sera pas forcément compris comme tu le souhaites. Par contre si tu dis "vulgaire" dans le sens *grossier*, alors je ne suis absolument pas d'accord. "Putain" c'est *vulgar*, "bled paumé" non. C'est familier.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Non, c'est encore trop haut, "paumé" n'est pas familier c'est populaire, voire argotique; le TLFi le mentionne : « arg. et pop.». Je dois avouer que je fais très mal les fines distinctions qu'il y a entre « vulgaire » et « grossier » en considérant les divers sens, je tends à amalgamer ces deux termes dans la lexicographie bien que le premier tende à signifier « ordinaire » et évidemment « ordinaire » n'est pas forcément « grossier ». Ce que j'entends par « vulgaire » correspond cependant à cette amalgamation et l'usage que fait de « vulgaire » le dictionnaire ; (champ 1)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat  cette amalgamation est bien faite : (TLFi) vulgaire : **Qui dénote la grossièreté**, le manque de distinction. Accent, intonation, rire, ton, voix vulgaire; air, allure, aspect, beauté, bouche, conduite, corps, figure, gaieté, laideur, physionomie vulgaire; goûts, manières vulgaires.